# Can't save .py file with german leters on mac

Tags: python, macos

I want to have a string `color = "weiß"` and when I enter this in my .py file on mac and save the file program crashes and doesn't save. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in your text editor.

Comment: Which code editor are you using? When you say "program crashes" do you mean your text editor or the python program you are running? Like Ignacio said, it may have nothing to do with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in your header

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

More info about encoding in Python source code in [`PEP 0263`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Answer (score 1):

To have unicode characters in your program, insert this to the first line:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

As shown in [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). This will allow you to put unicode strings directly inside the file.